# Make multi-line code indent work with sloppy selections in the editor

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, indentation

This is only a minor annoyance, but one at least I often run into.

Would it be possible to make the "indent code" button (or Ctrl+K) always indent entire lines when there's a multi-line selection? It already has logic for detecting a multi-line selection, so it shouldn't be too hard to make it extend it to the beginning/end of the first/last lines too.

Currently using the indent code button when you don't have the entire first/last line of a block selected results in something that most certainly isn't what you wanted, and pressing the button again to "undo" it doesn't even revert it back to what it used to be.

Most editors I've used indent entire blocks even if the first/last lines aren't entirely selected, and I'm sure I'm not the only one used to that. Selecting entire lines requires some precision mousing and I try to avoid that whenever possible, as it's slow.